# Delay is not working in java graphics

Tags: java, swing, animation, paintcomponent, thread-sleep

This is a code for drawing points on calculated locations by Bresenham's algorithm:

```
public void drawBresenhamPoints(Graphics2D g2, List<Point> bresenham) throws InterruptedException
{
       Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) g2;

    if(bresenham == null)
        return;

    g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);

    for(int i = 0; i < bresenham.size(); i = i+20)
    {
        int x = bresenham.get(i).x - pointWidth1/2;
        int y = bresenham.get(i).y - pointWidth1/2;

        int ovalW = pointWidth1;
        int ovalH = pointWidth1;

        g.fillOval(x, y, ovalW, ovalH);

            // delay
         try 
         {
             Thread.sleep(10);
         } 
         catch(Throwable e) 
         {
         System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
         }
    }
}
```

The list 'bresenham' contains all the points which are pre-calculated with the help of Bresenham's line drawing algorithm.  I want to set a delay of 1 second inside the 'for' loop so that each and every point is drawn after an interval of 1 second. The portion listed in the 'delay' section doesn't work. How to make 'delay' work?
    More specifically, I want to see all the points being drawn one by one on the screen in an interval of 1 second.

Comment: Read about Timer and don't use sleep to avoid EDT lock

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're calling this method in a `paint/paintComponent` method.

Just a pointer: **Never ever ever sleep the paint process**

Instead use a [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for repeated tasks. What *I* would do is

- Have two `Lists`. Your `List<Point> bresenham` and another `List<Point> paintList`. The `bresenham` will hold your data, and the `paintList` will be initially empty.
- Use the `paintList` to paint your points

  ```
  @override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

      for (Point p : paintList) {
          int x = bresenham.get(i).x - pointWidth1/2;
          int y = bresenham.get(i).y - pointWidth1/2;

          int ovalW = pointWidth1;
          int ovalH = pointWidth1;

          g.fillOval(x, y, ovalW, ovalH);
      }
  }
  ```
- Though there's nothing initially in the `paintList`, you will add a new `Point` to the list every firing of a timer event.

  ```
  Timer timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener(){
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          if (bresenham.isEmpty()) {
              ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
          } else {
              paintList.add(bresemham.get(0));
              bresenham.remove(0);
          }
          repaint();  
      }
  });
  timer.start();
  ```

  The basic timer of the constructor is firs the `delay`, which is the time delayed between *"iterations"*, and second argument in the listener that actually listens for the timer event that is fired every `delay` milliseconds. So what the code above basically does is add a `Point` to the `paintList` taken from the `bresenham` list, then removes the item the `repaint` which calls the `paintComponent`. When the list is empty, the timer will stop.

---

**UPDATE**

Here's a complete running example

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class BresenhamPoints extends JPanel {

    private static final int D_W = 500;
    private static final int D_H = 500;

    private List<Point> bresenhamList;
    private List<Point> paintList;

    public BresenhamPoints() {
        bresenhamList = createRandomPoints();
        paintList = new ArrayList<>();

        Timer timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (bresenhamList.isEmpty()) {
                    ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                } else {
                    paintList.add(bresenhamList.get(0));
                    bresenhamList.remove(0);
                }
                repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    private List<Point> createRandomPoints() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        List<Point> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            list.add(new Point(rand.nextInt(D_H), rand.nextInt(D_H)));
        }
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (Point p : paintList) {
            g.fillOval(p.x - 5, p.y - 5, 10, 10);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(D_W, D_H);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new BresenhamPoints());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value for the `sleep` method is in **milliseconds**, so there you are sleeping for 10ms. Changing it to 1000 will create a more noticeable interrupt.

As pointed out, you should never have any time consuming or even worse locking mechanisms on the EDT since it will hang your entire application. You could use a [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) to fire off events and draw one point at a time. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138017/java-drawing-on-jpanel-with-timer-delay) previous SO post should do what you need.